# Checking if a list of DateTime objs are coherent

Tags: c#

I've got list of DateTime objects that I need to check if they are a coherent time period.

How is this done?

There might be time gaps that I need to detect and act upon.

Edit:
From what I can see the DateTime objects are sorted.
I've got a TrackerObj class and Entry class the relevant however is only the timestamp in DateTime that each tracker holds:

```
    public class TrackerObj
    {
    private DateTime timeStamp;
    private string trackerId;
    private int voltage;

public TrackerObj(string trackerId, DateTime timeStamp, int voltage)
    {
        this.trackerId = trackerId;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.voltage = voltage;

    }


    }
```

The only relevant here is the timeStamp that from data I've seen are sorted.

Edit: The list is a List each object on that list contains a DateTime timeStamp. In order to determine if the periods between the DateTime are "coherent".

My definition of coherent time:
A period of time where each timestamp are after the other, without gaps (breaks in time).

DateTime format:

```
mm-dd-yyyy hours:minutes:seconds


private bool arePeriodsCoherent(List<TrackerObj> list)
{
// determine if all the objects on this list are without gaps. Return true if this is true. else return false.
for(int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
if(list[i].timeStamp > list[i + 1].timeStamp || list[i].timeStamp == list[i + 1].timeStamp)
{return false;}
else
{return true;}
}  
}
```

What variations does posible timeStamps contain? Will I the above code fail to catch all scenarios?

Comment: I think you need to expand on what you need here, maybe some sample code or some data

Comment: What is a "coherent" time period?

Comment: First is it a list or a dictionary?  They are not the same thing.  Second define what you mean by "coherent".  Do you mean you want to detect gaps?  If so what defines a gap exactly.  Some code or example data would be very helpful here.

Comment: coherent in my world means that there is no gaps in the time period between startdate and enddate.

Comment: @ryokan And how are you storing the start and end dates in your list or dictionary?  Are they sorted?  Please update your question will any additional information rather than putting it in the comments.

Comment: Please define "coherent". More important, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find any endpoints in a coherent timeperiod:

```
    private List<int> getTimeGapIndexEndPoints(double maxTimeGapSeconds)
    {

        int x = 1;

        List<int> timeLapsIndexes = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < trackerData[trackerId].currentList.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (x < trackerData[trackerId].currentList.Count())
            {
                DateTime t1 = trackerData[trackerId].currentList[i].TimeStamp;
                DateTime t2 = trackerData[trackerId].currentList[x++].TimeStamp;
                TimeSpan duration = t2.Subtract(t1);

                if (duration.TotalSeconds > maxTimeGapSeconds)
                {
                    // MessageBoxResult resultb = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(this, "After index: "+i+" "+duration+" Duration for trackerId: " + trackerId + " exceed " + maxTimeGapSeconds);
                    timeLapsIndexes.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return timeLapsIndexes;
        //for (int j = 0; j < timeLapsIndexes.Count(); j++)
        //{
        //    MessageBoxResult resultNumbers = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(this, "After Index (i+1): " + timeLapsIndexes[j] + " for trackerId: " + trackerId);
        //}
    }
```

Have a great day everyone. :)